Why do gaps in my blinds create multiple lines?
Multiple lines appear on my floor every morning from the gaps in my blinds.
Why does this happen and does it have to do with light being a wave, like in the double slit experiment? If so could it be that the second 'slit' is the gap underneath the blinds?
Could it be that the gap is acting as a focal point and the lines are caused by the railing outside?



I would rule out the interference, since the dimensions are too large. It can be some reflection. You could try to insert a foil of black paper somewhere, to block it. This will allow you to understand where it originates.

try to have a look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/685704/

What's the connection between the 2 photos? They look rather different, despite some similarities. Are they taken at roughly the same time? The same direction?

The slits are acting like a pinhole camera (although only in one dimension).   The nice shadows are likely images of something in front of the blinds.
Since the shadows are very regular, I'd suspect there is a railing with vertical supports in front of the window.   It could be something like trees or poles though.

These are really cool photos and they really do demonstrate the fascinating properties of light. However, the projections you're seeing are not just the direct result of light passing through slits. While the light does pass through the gaps in the blinds, the geometry of the patterns is likely influenced by additional factors such as the presence of objects blocking some of the light and the slight curvature of the blinds, which can angle the light in different ways.
